# REQ: Spring configured CXF ws client -- replacing hardcoded variables like 'address'

Tags: java, web-services, spring, cxf, configurable

I have to contact a Web Service (WS). I'm using JDK 1.6, maven 3.04, Spring 3.20 and apache's CXF 2.7.2. Using maven I created stubs for the WS by feeding it the wsdl file. I have a spring config for the WS client and it looks something like

servlet-context.xml

```
<jaxws:client id="paymentClient" serviceClass="com.xxx.payment.Payment"
    address="http://127.0.0:8088/mockPaymentBinding" <!-- SOAPUI mock -->
    username="username"
    password="secret" />
<!- username and password are for wsdl basic authentication -->
```

In the Java code it looks something like

```
@Autowired 
com.xxx.payment.Payment client;
..
// Set all needed parameters.
PaymentGetBalanceResponse response = null;
PaymentGetBalance getBalance = new PaymentGetBalance();
RequestGetBalance value = new RequestGetBalance();
value.setTransactionId("transActionId");
getBalance.setRequest(value );

// Now call the WS and get the response
response = client.getBalance(getBalance); // generated by the cxf -client argument.
```

The "response" line is generated as an example by CXF. Then Eclipse tells me something is missing (getbalance) and optionally creates it for me above the line. Then something else is (value) missing and so on. In the end all parameters are correctly filled in. All the missing stuff/variables/objects are in the generated stubs code.

This works like a charm BUT the address is atm hardcoded in the spring config. The configuarion parameters for the application are stored in a simple database. The contents is accesible using a spring bean so I can get at the variables in the end in the code using something like config.getValue(URL);

I hoped to being able to change the 'address' (url WS) in the code above but haven't found a way to do that. Can't find setters in the generated stub code. An alternative would be to use variables in the spring servlet-context.xml file BUT those variables have to come from the database. Second alternative. I probably/hopefully get away with starting at the bottom and using the Objectfactorys (in the stubs) to create objects. Then setting the correct parameter (either in the 'new' or a setter) and then work my way to the top. A colleguee has done this (not for 'address') and this seems to work but the code is suboptimal/'messy' at best. ALSO I would like to able to have the username and password configurable, NOT static. Did quite a bit of RTM at the CXF sites but to no avail.

Read something about JaxWsProxyFactoryBean but can't figure out how to apply it here as I use Springs @autowire functionality.

I've been breaking my brains about this issue but it seems my neurons are running in circles. ANY help/pointers is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From CXF User Guide: [**How to override the service address?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321884/req-spring-configured-cxf-ws-client-replacing-hardcoded-variables-like-addr).

If I've inferred the spring config correctly, I think this will do:

```
   @Autowired
   com.xxx.payment.Payment client;
   // ... 
   BindingProvider provider = (BindingProvider)client.getServicePort();
   // You can set the address per request here
   provider.getRequestContext().put(
        BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
        "http://my/new/url/to/the/service");
```